# Displaying shuffles answers in an array in their tags

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const btn_start = document.getElementById("start");
let container = document.getElementById("container");
let questionTag = document.getElementById("question");
let answerTag = document.getElementsByClassName("answer");

btn_start.addEventListener("click", startQuiz);

const myQuestions = [
    {
        question: "What's 2+2?",
        answers: [
            { text: "4", correct: true },
            { text: "2", correct: false },
            { text: "10", correct: false },
            { text: "1", correct: false },
        ],
    },
];
function startQuiz() {
    container.style.visibility = "visible";
    btn_start.style.visibility = "hidden";
    showQuestion(myQuestions[0]);
}
function showQuestion(questionAndAnswers) {
    const shuffledAnswers = _.shuffle(questionAndAnswers.answers);
    questionTag.innerText = questionAndAnswers.question;
    shuffledAnswers.forEach((answer, idx) => {
        
    });
}
```

```html
        <h3 id="question"></h3>
        <div class="answers">
            <button id="answer1" class="answer"></button>
            <button id="answer2" class="answer"></button>
            <button id="answer3" class="answer"></button>
            <button id="answer4" class="answer"></button>
        </div>
```

After putting my answers and question in an array object, I shuffled them with lodash and was able to display the question in its right tag, how do I display the Shuffled answers in the answerTag. I keep getting errors of trouble reading text in my .foreach function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myQuestions = [
    {
        question: "What's 2+2?",
        answers: [
            { text: "4", correct: true }[0],
            { text: "2", correct: false }[1],
            { text: "10", correct: false }[2],
            { text: "1", correct: false }[3],
        ],
    },
];
```

why you need a [number]?, i think the array should be

```js
const myQuestions = [
    {
        question: "What's 2+2?",
        answers: [
            { text: "4", correct: true },
            { text: "2", correct: false },
            { text: "10", correct: false },
            { text: "1", correct: false },
        ],
    },
];
```

Comment: My fault, just changed it. any suggestions on how to resolve my issue

Comment: in `answerTag[0] = answer` is `anserTag[0]` a dom ?, where do you get it ? may it be `document.getElementById('answer'+idx).innerText = answer.text` ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have [0] [1] [2] [3] at the end of your answers array objects?

Kindly remove them and try again. Coz this is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

First you have collect the buttons. Then you iterate the buttons and put the text to every single button. Like that:

```js
const answers = [
  { text: "4", correct: true },
  { text: "2", correct: false },
  { text: "10", correct: false },
  { text: "1", correct: false },
];


const at = document.querySelectorAll('.answer');

for (let i = 1; i <= at.length; ++i) {  
  at[i-1].innerHTML = answers[i-1].text; 
}
```

```html
       <h3 id="question"></h3>
        <div class="answers">
            <button id="answer1" class="answer"></button>
            <button id="answer2" class="answer"></button>
            <button id="answer3" class="answer"></button>
            <button id="answer4" class="answer"></button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do i put that in my forEach?

Comment: @kiro you can use foreach or for loop. i prefer the for loop because i can better handle the index